# Disable log of specified crontab item

Tags: scripting, cron, logs, syslog

How can i disable logging for specified item/line in crontab? (i´m on debian/raspbian)

I have a script that checks if wlan0 is up every minute, but i don't like that cron logs every minute on syslog :/

This is my crontab item:

```
* *     * * *   root    /home/scripts/chkwlan0
```

Please, if anyone can help, i'll appreciate it.

Thanks in advance.

Gtz, Sergio.

Comment: what log lines do you object to?

Comment: i have this line in syslog: 
Jan  1 21:13:01 hostname /USR/SBIN/CRON[16152]: (root) CMD (   /home/scripts/chkwlan0)

Answer (score 1):

Ok the easieet way to blobk that log line is to not use cron to launch your script.

Have your script re-run itself every 60 seconds instead. then it need only be launched once, eg by /etc/inittab.

Comment: u r rite, maybe your way is better. thanks.